# How do I get this element using Jquery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the previous "Shown" row to the row using the onclick event on a button. I am using datatables, the datatable expands to show children in a row inserted after the "Shown" row.

e.g.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd shown"> <!-- I want to get this row by it's class/role -->
<tr><tr> <!-- This is a comment row with a button that submits aforementioned comments -->
<tr role="row" class="even"> <!-- This row is not expanded -->
```

That being said here is a sizable chunk of my actual code (minus the js).

```
<tr role="row" class="odd shown">
        <td class=" details-control"></td>
        <td class="sorting_1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <div style="text-center">
                <table class="table" style="background:transparent;width:100%;">
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="container text-center col-md-offset-2 col-md-8" id="commentDiv"><label for="applicantComment"><h4>
                Add comment</h4></label><br><textarea class="form-control" id="applicantComment1"
                                                      style="resize:none;width:100%;height:100px;"></textarea>

                <div><br></div>
                <div class="container text-center col-md-offset-2 col-md-8" style="width:inherit;">
                    <div class="intro-text"><a class="btn btn-xl" value="1" id="submit">Submit</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're using jQuery `$(".shown")` will grab any elements with the `.shown` class.

Comment: what is being clicked and where is it?

Comment: @charlietfl The button <a class="btn btn-xl"...</a> is what is being clicked.

Comment: @sharf The problem is I need the closest shown to the button. (I've tried .closest('shown'), .closest('.shown'), and pretty much every other variety :|)

Answer (score 1):

You want to move up to closest `<tr>` then get the previous row from what i understand

```
$('.btn-xl').click(function(){
   var $shownRow = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
   $shownRow.doSomething();
});
```